# How to nest code within a list using Markdown

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, list

Oftentimes, I want to include code samples in a list, for example:

1. Item One
2. Item Two, for example:

   ```
   private bool ItemTwo()
   {
   return this.IFeelLucky;
   }
   ```
3. Item Three

<s>The problem is that there isn't a good and intuitive way to do this using [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). It's doable, but you have to do some formatting black-magic to get it that way, which is just not "nice" to deal with.</s>

Source that produces this:

```
1. Item One
2. Item Two, for example:
<br/><br/><pre><code>private bool ItemTwo()
    {
        return this.IFeelLucky;
    }</code></pre>
3. Item Three
```

---

I would love to just be able to do it this way:

```
1. Item One
2. Item Two, for example:

    private bool Test()
    {
        return this.IFeelLucky;
    }

3. Item Three
```

Which results in, well, this:

1. Item One
2. Item Two, for example:

   private bool Test()
   {
   return this.IFeelLucky;
   }
3. Item Three

---

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)

Comment: Seems a little silly to close as a dupe a FAQ question, either close in the other direction, or move the FAQ tag.

Answer (score 314, accepted):

Code is possible in markdown (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/3431#3431)) - you just have to leave a blank line and then indent by **8 spaces** as a minimum.

The text below

```
* example

        this.isSomeCode = true;

*  
        addMoreCode();
```

will generate this:

- example

  ```
  this.isSomeCode = true;
  ```
- ```
  addMoreCode();
  ```

Comment: I see. Somehow I didn't try that, and I had missed it on the markdown editing help page as well.

Comment: That's because it seems very counter-intuitive. Thank you for posting this, I had been despairing of doing the same thing.

Comment: There should be an easier way to increase and decrease indenting then, because all I did was use the predefined `Ctrl-J` indent mechanism and it didn't work.  How is anyone to know that you have to do an extra 4 spaces, and then if you have a lot of lines, you have to insert these for for each and every one.  Not only counterintuitive, but annoying.  I do know that if you put a single character at the beginning of a line, you can force it to move over, but that is not intuitive either, esp for nubes.

Comment: @a_m0d, How can we do it without having the first hanging line `example`?

Comment: @Pacerier I've added an example on the last line - basically just add the bullet point, 2 spaces behind it (to make it a list item), and then start your code on the next line

Comment: @a_m0d, Actually the other day [Brad had solved it using `<!-- -->`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown/248399#comment854901_7837) , but nice, this solution is better and more straightforward.

Comment: In my case 4 spaces worked

Answer (score 106):

If you want to add a block of code to a list item, you have to add an extra 4 spaces for every level of that list. You also have to make sure that you leave a blank line before the code block.

```D
code block outside of a list
```

- Main list

  ```D
  code block
  ```

  - sub list

    ```D
    code block
    ```

    ```D
    second code block
    ```

    - sub<sup>2</sup> list

      ```D
      code block
      ```

      - sub<sup>3</sup> list

        ```D
        code block
        ```

    ```D
    up two list levels
    ```

```D
# 4↴
    code block outside of a list

- Main list
#     8↴
        code block
# 4↴
    - sub list

#        12↴
            code block
#     8↴
        <!-- --> # can also be used to set highlighting <!-- language: lang-none -->
#        12↴
            second code block
#     8↴
        - sub<sup>2</sup> list

#            16↴
                code block
#        12↴
            - sub<sup>3</sup> list
#                20↴
                    code block
#     8↴
        <!-- -->
#        12↴
            up two list levels
```

If you need to force the Markdown processor to start a new section, just add a `<p/>` or `<!-- -->` on it's own line at the appropriate level. That's how I managed to follow a list with a code block for this answer.
[If you do use `<!-- -->` you can use it to set the highlighting mode for the following code block as well (`<!-- language: lang-none -->`)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: nice example, thx.

Comment: The <p/> trick is brilliant - thanks!

Comment: I now use an HTML comment, instead of `<p/>` .

Comment: It would be nice if the code button on the format bar above the edit box did that.

Comment: +1 : You also have to make sure that you leave a blank line before the code block

Comment: @BradGilbert, How can we do it without the preceding line? If I use `<p>`, the "dot" (or numeral) don't appear.

Comment: @Pacerier try using `<!-- -->`. ( That's just a guess, I have no idea what you are talking about. If you post a link to the post I can look at the source and tell you what you need to do. )

Comment: @BradGilbert, Nice, `<!-- -->` works on Chrome. I think you've just invented the solution to this problem.

Comment: @BradGilbert, I found a better solution: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown/3793#comment873211_3793

Answer (score 16):

````
1. Item One
2. Item Two, for example:

    ```private bool Test()
    {
        return this.IFeelLucky;
    }
    ```

3. Item Three
````

works:

1. Item One
2. Item Two, for example:

   `private bool Test()
   {
       return this.IFeelLucky;
   }`
3. Item Three

Or indent again to have a prettier code block:

```
1. Item One
2. Item Two, for example:

        private bool Test()
        {
            return this.IFeelLucky;
        }

3. Item Three
```

Like this:

1. Item One
2. Item Two, for example:

   ```
   private bool Test()
   {
       return this.IFeelLucky;
   }
   ```
3. Item Three

Comment: How can we do it without having the first hanging line?

Comment: @Pacerier What do you mean?

Comment: Taking  your example number "2", the hanging line is `Item Two, for example:`. How to do it without the hanging line?

Comment: @Pacerier I'm still not sure what you mean by "hanging" but it's possible to remove it.

Comment: If I remove it, the dot disappears in Chrome. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown/248399#comment854851_117087 . But thanks anyway, Brad has solved the problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown/248399#comment857223_7837

Comment: This is wrong. Triple backticks only trigger a code block in Github Flavored Markdown, not in official Markdown (which is [at least currently] used on Stack Exchange). What you have there is four separate pieces of inline code.

Comment: The triple backticks save 4 spaces per line, at the cost of a unified code block. I don't see why the block is recognized as code yet the lines are rendered separately.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman This is because Markdown has support for using any number of backticks for inline code formatting. This is to allow for including backticks in your inline code, like ```` ``` `` ``` ```` to give ``` `` ``` (this is not supported in comments though, apparently). Now, Stack Exchange IMO _should_ be using GFM because it's ridiculous to require indentation for code in a web-based editor where nobody views the source and the TAB key doesn't work. But as it stands, this technique is objectively wrong since it does not produce a Markdown code block.

Answer (score 15):

This is all documented in the editing help, that little [?] button above the editor.

It's also linked from the sidebar of every edit page.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Ok. Now that I look again I see it. Somehow I missed it the first time.

Comment: Wish I could accept multiple answers because this is really helpful too.

Comment: You should edit that guide to include @BradGilbert 'You also have to make sure that you leave a blank line before the code block'

Comment: Could you perhaps also add UI support for this? The `{}` button above the textbox only toggles the indentation on multiple clicks, doesn't increase the indentation. Having to do it manually (or to copy back and forth to a text editor) on long code blocks is pretty tiresome.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, (recall the rest of this comment from all your LQP review experiences)

Comment: [this is the specific section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists) of the help docs that explains this particular issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to start a list item with a block of code, rather than text, you need to add at least a space character after the bullet or number, then make two line breaks before starting to indent the code block with 8 spaces.

In the following examples, line breaks are denoted by the ↵ symbol.

---

- ```
  unordered
  ```

```
 - ↵
↵
        example
```

---

1. ```
   ordered
   ```

```
1. ↵
↵
        example
```

---

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7187588/106224) for a real-world example.

Comment: The line heights do look a little awkward though...

Comment: How to show the "dot" (or numeral index)?

Comment: @Pacerier: You mean the dot in "1."? It should be there.

Comment: Ok, seems to work on FireFox... but this is what Chrome sees: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yaKGq.png

Comment: Update: Brad has managed to do it, via `<!-- -->` http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown/248399#comment857223_7837

Comment: @Pacerier: Wow. Another stupid Chrome bug.