# List entry followed by code block messes up the code section

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, code, list

Here's two examples (note that in first example, backticks also had no effect, for some reason):

- `include/db.php`:

  `$attribs =  
              array(
                      PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => $config['db']['persistent'],
                      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => $config['db']['errormode']
              );


      $db = new PDO(
              $config['db']['uri'],
              $config['db']['user'],
              $config['db']['pass'],
              $attribs
      );
      $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
      $db->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");`


  } catch (PDOException $e) {
          print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "
  ";
          die();
  }

  function dbGetEngine() {
          global $config;
          return substr($config['db']['uri'], 0, strpos($config['db']['uri'], ':'));
  }
  ?>
- `include/config.php`:

It gets worse, try adding space prior to the asterisk :/

Just removing the asterisk fixes stuff up. Thing is, I believe it looks nicer with the asterisk ... and it's definitely a bug :-)

Comment: definitely check out the editing help, which covers this in some detail http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to embed code in a list, you'll need to [precede it with 8 spaces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown) instead of the usual 4:

- `include/db.php`:

  ```
  try {

          $attribs =  
                  array(
                          PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => $config['db']['persistent'],
                          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => $config['db']['errormode']
                  );


          $db = new PDO(
                  $config['db']['uri'],
                  $config['db']['user'],
                  $config['db']['pass'],
                  $attribs
          );
          $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
          $db->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

  } catch (PDOException $e) {
          print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
          die();
  }

  function dbGetEngine() {
          global $config;
          return substr($config['db']['uri'], 0, strpos($config['db']['uri'], ':'));
  }
  ?>
  ```
- `include/config.php`:

  ```
  //$config['db']['uri'] = 'sqlite:' . realpath('.') . '/site.db'; // PDO's database access URI
  $config['db']['uri'] = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sitedb'; // server should be : 195.78.32.7
  //$config['db']['uri'] = 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=sitedb';
  $config['db']['user'] = 'user_goes_here'; // database username
  $config['db']['pass'] = 'pass_goes_here'; // database password
  $config['db']['persistent'] = false; // should the connection be persistent
  $config['db']['errormode'] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION; // PDO's error mode

  ?>
  ```

Comment: FAQ perhaps? Seems like this would be helpful.

Comment: OK, I added the FAQ tag to the original post.

Comment: Interesting ... yet, I still believe that markdown breaking horribly like it does is not productive; I mean, it actually ate up a few lines of my code. Not here; hete it ate one out of config.php, but it looks worse in JS-generated preview, and confuses the hell out of someone not knowing what's wrong... Just saying. :-)