# List preceding code prevents indented code from being displayed properly

Tags: support, status-bydesign, markdown

I see something similar [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3930/bug-list-entry-followed-by-code-messes-code-up).

I figured I'd post my situation since it's a different situation (as I'm not trying to add my code into the list).  Also, I didn't try to use a markup numbered list, I just numbered it myself.

For example:

1. added a TRibbonCombobox on the ribbon bar
2. added an event handler

   procedure TfrmRibbonDemo.RibbonComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     if RibbonComboBox1.Text='Luna' then
       Ribbon1.Style:=RibbonLunaStyle
       else
       Ribbon1.Style:=RibbonSilverStyle;
   end;

On the other hand, if a list doesn't immediately precede it:

```
procedure TfrmRibbonDemo.RibbonComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if RibbonComboBox1.Text='Luna' then
    Ribbon1.Style:=RibbonLunaStyle
    else
    Ribbon1.Style:=RibbonSilverStyle;
end;
```

Comment: Dupe of a dupe of a dupe.  First one I dug up was this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/why-is-a-code-block-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-i but there are tons of others.

Answer (score 3):

1. added a TRibbonCombobox on the ribbon bar
2. added an event handler

   ```
   procedure TfrmRibbonDemo.RibbonComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     if RibbonComboBox1.Text='Luna' then
       Ribbon1.Style:=RibbonLunaStyle
       else
       Ribbon1.Style:=RibbonSilverStyle;
   end;
   ```

Indent 8 spaces [per the documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help), which is linked via the little "help" icon in the upper right of toolbar, and again on the right sidebar when editing.

Comment: But what if you don't want the code as part of list item `2.` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Handler Demo With continues Progress bar for Anroid**

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Handler extends Activity {

```
private ProgressDialog pd;
private TextView tv;
private android.os.Handler hand, handler;



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "please wait...","retrive ddata...", true);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    hand = new android.os.Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            System.out.println("in handler---------->");
            pd.dismiss();
            handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 3000);
        }

     };

     hand.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 5000);  // handleMessage() call from here

     handler = new android.os.Handler()
     {
         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
         {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             super.handleMessage(msg);
             pd.show();
             hand.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 5000);
         }
      };

} //end of onCreate method
```

} //end of main class