# When placing code directly after a list, the code is not recognized. Is this a bug?

Tags: bug, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)

When placing code directly after a list. The code is not recognized. See the example below.

```
- something

    some code
```

looks like this:

- something

  some code

should look like this:

- something

```
some code
```

Comment: This is a dupe, ill find it in a sec.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3930/bug-list-entry-followed-by-code-messes-code-up

Comment: no It's not. The other was about putting code into a list. This is about putting code after a list. The solution there was to put 8 spaces instead of 4 spaces before the code. 8 spaces make the code be part of the list.

Comment: agree, not quite a duplicate, but also something that can be tested at the http://babelmark.bobtfish.net/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you absolutely, positively must have code RIGHT AFTER a bulleted list, then you need something between the two elements to seperate them. You can use an HTML comment or other non-printable element (say, a `&nbsp;`), like so.

- item1
- item2

```
 this is code
```

Comment: ... or indent it by 8 spaces.

Comment: Still, why is it not simply possible to provide the functionality of having code format directly after the list item (and not as a part of the list, but starting on the far left) then, without such a workaround here? Is this not a feature-request or bug that is yet to be handled on meta?