# Is SO's code formatting broken?

Tags: support, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When placing code directly after a list, the code is not recognized. Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29582/when-placing-code-directly-after-a-list-the-code-is-not-recognized-is-this-a-bu)

Notice how [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961134/why-does-my-algorithm-not-work) are 4 spaces of code before each line of code. The import statement at the top is not in the code block because if I indent it 4 spaces, even more sections break. Is something wrong? This worked yesterday.

Comment: This is the [old "Code Block after Numbered List" bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29582/when-placing-code-directly-after-a-list-the-code-is-not-recognized-is-this-a-bu). Just add `<!-- Ridiculous -->` between the numbered list and the import statement before you indent it, and it should work. Most people suggest an &nbsp;, but using an HTML comment makes it flow much more smoothly (that is, there won't be a hideous empty line between the code and the list).

Comment: I just added some text to help transition into the code.

Comment: @Grace - put that into an answer so I can accept it.