# Problem with code sample formating

Tags: markdown, code-formatting, support

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338075/asp-modalpopupextender-not-displaying-detail-view/3354276#3354276) question :

If i remove the lone "(" the code sample disappear...

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3930/list-entry-followed-by-code-block-messes-up-the-code-section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a char between the list and the code, or indent it a few more spaces if you want it to be part of the list item.

As it seems that what you want to do is the code to be separated, I just deleted de `(` and replaced it with a `<!-- html comment -->`.