# Code after bullet list isn't rendered correctly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editor, code, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to nest code within a list using markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown)

- If there is a list immediately followed by a code block the code block is not recognized as code
- (Even though there is a newline between the two).

  int answer = 42;

  **Note:** This happens both in the WMD preview and in the final (server rendered) post.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Inside a bullet list

To place a code block inside a list item, use *eight* spaces to format the code.

```
- item 1

        code

- item 2
```

Result:

- item 1

  ```
  code
  ```
- item 2

### After a bullet list

To place a code block after a bullet list, add an empty comment between them.

```
- item 1
- item 2

<!-- -->

    code
```

Result:

- item 1
- item 2

```
code
```

Since Markdown doesn't have a way to explicitly end a list, there has to be *something* to make it start a new section of formatting.

Comment: Oh, I think maybe I was answering a different question. Oops.

Comment: I will often just put in a <p/>, on it's own line.

Comment: IMO, A better solution is to just indent by 8 spaces instead of 4