# Why does code formatting not work

Tags: support, code-formatting

In my answer [Auto-Fetch All YouTube Videos From Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214224/auto-fetch-all-youtube-videos-from-account/2220468#2220468) I can't get code formatting to work. What do I do wrong?

Ok, I understand it was still in the list. However, I used two linebreaks between my last listitem and the code. How much linebreaks should I use then?

Comment: Extra four spaces: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

I recommend avoiding code inside lists, personally, but you need to indent 8 spaces.

Comment: Another note on this...  Once you have a list in your answer, if you want to insert code that is *not* at the list level, you must have at least one non-blank, non-list line before the code (a horizontal rule works well) in order to break out of the "list" logic and allow the code to be formatted correctly.  (See o.k.w's answer below, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096866/sql-server-need-a-sql-query-to-identify-highlight-specific-changes-in-an-audit/3113525#3113525 for an example that I just edited.)

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is a bit late, but I thought it might add some new perspective to the conversation.

Since about 2015, the best way -- in my opinion -- to enter code is with Stack Exchange's code snippets. This can be done by clicking the little icon to the right of the picture/image icon, or by using the keyboard shortcut **CTRL + M** (CMD + M on Mac). This is the best way I have found to make sure your code appears as code and doesn't not get accidentally translated. You can past mixed html/javascript/css all in the html box, or you can separate each part into individual boxes.

Works much like jsfiddle, without needing to leave Stack Overflow, or rely on a link that might disappear in a few years.

Answer (score 0):

A list:

- item 1
- item 2

  function(code-in-a-list){
    //with four leading spaces
  }

The Code: (this line ends the list too)

```
function(code-outside-a-list){
  //with four leading spaces too
}
```