# Code detection not working

Tags: support, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does code formatting not work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38665/why-does-code-formatting-not-work)

Can you tell me why code detection is not working in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862583/affine-transform-with-interpolation/7939279#7939279)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside numbered lists, you need to add two levels of indentation (= 8 characters).

I fixed it for you.

Comment: And I fixed the numbered list for you ;-)

Comment: Not just numbered lists, regular bullet lists too.