# Markdown editor does not handle code correctly in lists

Tags: bug, markdown, editor

Note that this is *not* complaining about *the fact* that 8 spaces are needed for code in lists. It is complaining that the editor doesn't seem to respect this.

As Markdown specifies, 8 spaces are needed in code within a list, as shown at the example at the bottom of this post.

However, when I try to change it to code using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, it tries to add the four spaces if they aren't there, but when there are four spaces within the list, which is *not* code as per the definition, and I request it adds code, it seems to make things worse by removing the spaces and potentially throwing off the list even more. Can we have the markdown editor be intelligent so when a user requests code be added, it doesn't cut the four spaces thinking code(which isn't around in the first place) is to be removed?

This is an example of what it needs to make:

```
1. Random List

        random code

2. Entry 2
```

produces:

1. Random List

   ```
   random code
   ```
2. Entry 2

but instead if makes it 0 spaces before the code.

Comment: Yes, this is known.

Comment: I believe this was even brought up somewhere these last few days.

Comment: Dupe link? I didn't see it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152331/alter-format-as-code-button-ctrlk-to-detect-when-your-selection-is-in-a-l Which was closed as a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49782/can-the-code-button-in-the-format-bar-be-made-to-work-for-code-blocks-in-numbere

Comment: @Bart Can the master post be made to clearly show this feature request?