# Automatic code snippet formatting inside list

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the code button in the format bar be made to work for code blocks in numbered lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49782/can-the-code-button-in-the-format-bar-be-made-to-work-for-code-blocks-in-numbere)

Is it possible to have an automatic formatting of a code snippet inside a list?
E.g., If I want something like this:

- Some words

  ```
  some code
  some more code
  ```

The standard <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> shifts right 4 spaces only and it's not enough if inside a list. So I had to manually shift the block another 4 spaces. Is it possible to auto-detect being inside list and making an appropriate 8-place shift?

Comment: The title here is somewhat misleading, since you're aware of how exactly to Markdown a code snippet within a list, but you're really referring to the post editor not knowing.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I've edited, hope it's more verbose now