# Can't show xml code?

Tags: support, code-formatting, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to nest code within a list using markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown)

I'm trying to put XML code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8476401/1583), but it's not displaying at all.  I tried using the code formatter and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> (which is the same thing), but it doesn't matter.  Here is the code:

```
<up:MultiUploader type="LABEL" ui:field="uploader" servletPath="/...     /SampleUploadServlet" styleName="{style.myup}" maximumFiles="2" avoidRepeatFiles="true"   validExtensions="xml"/>
```

It appears immediately after a list item.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've formatted the code in this question as code, and it shows for me now.

Comment: Do you have a link to the question in question?

Comment: Realted: [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3327/52738)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I took a look at [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8476401/1583) and the issue is that the XML appears immediately after a list.

When formatting code that falls within the context of a list, you need to indent it a further 4 spaces for a total of 8:

1. My list

   ```
   <myxml code>
   ```
2. More list

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you for the answer and the edit!