# Problem with code formatting in numbered lists

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to nest code within a list using markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown)

Is there any way to use SO's numbered list implementation to render [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9500380/403455)?  I played with this for quite a while and couldn't seem to coax the renderer to mix formatted code with a numbered list.  I ended up not using the numbered list to work around it.

Comment: Fixed that for you :)

Comment: This issue also occurs in unordered lists. @balpha - What is the fix? 8 indenting spaces?