# Code blocks not formatted depending on surrounding context

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)

I was just submitting a new answer to an old question on Stackoverflow and noticed my code block was not being formatted as code.

It was originally positioned between a bulleted list and some plain text.

I discovered that when I cut and paste it to after the plain text it would be formatted correctly, but pasting it back in its old positions would always be without format. Adding blank lines around it made no difference.

Here's a screenshot of the same code block in both positions showing the first unformatted and the second correctly formatted:
[image: formatting bug screenshot]

Let's see what happens here:

```
var foo = 'bar'; // works
```

- random
- bullet
- list

  var bar = 'foo'; // doesn't work

Comment: [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)

Comment: [How to nest code within a list using markdown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown)

Answer (score 3):

To have a code block immediately after a list, you can put a HTML comment between them:

```
 * item 1
 * item 2

<!-- -->

    code block
```

**Result:**

- item 1
- item 2

```
code block
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside list markdown, you need to indent 8-spaces for code sample.

Example markdown:

```
- List Item

        /** code block */
```

Markdown output:

- List Item

  ```
  /** code block */
  ```

Comment: This is handy to know, but it actually makes the code block itself part of a list item, which is not what I was trying to achieve. [hammar's workaround](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156041/154292) hits the nail on the head though.