# Allow codeblocks in Lists

Tags: support, status-completed, markdown

when trying to create a list and including a code-block in one of the points, either you can't properly format the codeblock as such, or you reset the numbered list counter.

imagine following scenario:

1. Some explanation or reasoning
   adding a language declaration to make the codeblock render

```
here comes the codeblock
```

1. Second point in chain of reasoning

Comment: @m0sa - or better `status-already-completed`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works as described in the markdown help:

[image]

Comment: aaaah I was searching under List...

Answer (score 6):

Code within lists needs additional indentation (8-spaces):

1. Some explanation or reasoning
   adding a language declaration to make the codeblock render

   ```
   here comes the codeblock
   ```
2. Second point in chain of reasoning

Markdown:

```
1. Some explanation or reasoning  
adding a language declaration to make the codeblock render

        here comes the codeblock

2. Second point in chain of reasoning
```

See: [How to nest code within a list using Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown)