# Unable to post answer with formatted code

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting

I have been trying to post an answer to this question:

[Activate CSS3 animation when the content scrolls into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325679/activate-css3-animation-when-the-content-scrolls-into-view)

I have read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) but apparently I miss something probably obvious here because I am not able to post my answer. I get an error:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code...

I have pasted my answer [here](http://pastebin.com/XacWqzvJ). As you can see, there are two blocks of codes, one with `<script>` tags and the other with `$(window).load()`.

In an initial attempt, I simply formatted them with the `{}` icon which tabbed them by 4 spaces. Neither of them was appearing in the preview though, so I placed the `<pre><code>` tags but again the same error kept coming, being unable to submit the answer.

What is wrong with the code blocks?

UPDATE: After @Mat 's comments, and since there have been no answers regarding to this, I would like to make clear that partly it has been my fault that I have not properly understood that 8 spaces are necessary for code formatting within lists. Nevertheless, I change the question tag to 'bug' since I believe that it would be best for the user interface if the relevant code formatting button would recognize that the code is in a list and add the necessary spaces by itself rather than getting a validation error on posting.

Comment: That's a bit strange. Try removing the `<pre><code>` markup, and indent by 8 spaces (necessary for code within lists).

Comment: @Mat thanks for your comment, appreciated. This worked, that's what I was missing: didn't know that in lists 8 spaces were required. Although I would think that the relevant icon should format it appropriately anyway.

Comment: @Mat Would you mind adding that as an answer for future reference?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI: that part is already documented [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown?rq=1), but I'm wondering if this report isn't a bug - I don't see a reason for the post to have been denied using pre/code tags. So won't answer, to make it more likely that someone in the know has a look at it.