# Syntax highlighting for form elements sometimes do not work

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting, html-entities

I [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162451/vue-when-to-use-keyup-native-in-input-elements) that has this code

```
<input type="text" v-model="myVar" @keyup.enter="doFilter" />
<button class="md-icon-button md-raised md-accent md-dense" @click="doFilter">Filter</button>
```

and it does not work unless I add in this

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
```

Is that a bug?

### Update 1: Example of code section not working

Here is the exact 2 lines from above, without the syntax highlighting hint

Filter

I cannot reproduce it when I indent the code here. Is there a stackoverflow sandbox where I can create a test question?

Comment: Not a bug. The question has no HTML tag.

Comment: The problem you see is caused by the fact you have a numbered list in front of that code block. a `<br>` or any other markup including a comment will break the numbered list and show you your code.

Comment: There is a sandbox: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox You can create test answers there.

Comment: @rene Thank you, that is exactly the problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3792/206131 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3327/206131 are rekated

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you, that is  good to know :)