# Unable to rollback to previous revision

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, rollbacks

I edited [my answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/47250/3-3v-pro-micro-clones-flashing-leds-after-1200-bps-touch/56648#56648) because the information was no longer accurate.

However, after editing I found that the formatting was broken, so I rolled it back to the previous version.

Unfortunately after the rollback the formatting is *still* broken.

How to get back to the proper formatting?

This is what it looks right now:

[image: After]

Note the code block is not part of the list item and the number start over.

This is how it looked before:

[image: Before]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer previously used an unsupported format for code blocks, which rendered differently. We now support code fences, which changes how the post gets rendered in the current engine. In short, it's not possible to return it to its previous rendering because the post is getting run through a different version of the rendering engine now.

That aside, we have a FAQ question for how to properly format code inside a list item: [How to nest code within a list using Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown)