# Markdown: Code directly after a list (and not as part of that list)

Tags: support, markdown

Sometimes, when I answer a question, I use a list to explain things and add some code after that, for example:

- argument 1 is hoppa
- argument 2 is klap
- argument 3 is klap

  command hoppa klap klap

The command however is not formatted correctly on Stack Overflow. When I add a line between them (which basically does not mean anything)

- argument 1 is hoppa
- argument 2 is klap
- argument 3 is klap

blah blah:

```
command hoppa klap klap
```

The code is formatted correctly.

Adding two spaces extra, will produce code that seems part of the last list item, which is not what is meant.

- argument 1 is hoppa
- argument 2 is klap
- argument 3 is klap

  ```
  command hoppa klap klap
  ```

The question is closed with a referral to a completely different question: that of nesting code in a list. Also some comments point to that. This question is **not** about nesting code in a list. If you look at the accepted answer, you will also see that this is not the case.

Comment: You need an extra level of indent (4 space) for code block in a list. In you example 2 extra space will fix it ...

Comment: Duplicate of the [tag:faq] post [How to nest code within a list using Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown). If this FAQ doesn’t apply to the current CommonMark parser, it should really be updated…

Comment: Not a bug - indented lines after a list item are continuations of the list item, so you either need to: indent further to put a code block in the list item; use a code fence to put code straight after a list; or otherwise explicitly end the list before adding an indented code block.

Comment: @DavidPostill; @user289905 : no. that is not what I asked.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Ok. A code block instead of the four space indent works as well. I would, however have expected that an empty line after the list would explicitly end the list.

Comment: @LjmDullaart I've added why that's not the case to my answer.

Comment: Please research including googling the [help]/FAQ & site:[meta.se] before considering asking a question. [Why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350701/stack-overflow-bug-code-directly-after-a-list#comment1174269_350701)

Comment: I did before posting, and I did also just now. All I can find are answers that would make the code part of the list-item which is, as I stated again and again, not the question, ans this answer. So please, instead of just saying "use google" enlighten me to what search-terms would produce the answer to the question.

Comment: This question is a duplicate, of this answer on the question this is closed again: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7837/361484

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is intentional, and allows continuation paragraphs in list items, so this Markdown:

```
 - first

 - second 

    code block
```

Renders to:

> - first
> - second
>
>   code block

---

Instead, use the code fence block style to add code right after a list, e.g. this:

````
 - first

 - second

```
code block
```
````

Renders to:

> - first
> - second
>
> ```
> code block
> ```

---

Alternatively, note that you can explicitly (but invisibly) end the list with an empty comment:

```
 - first

 - second 

<!-- -->

    code block
```

Also renders to:

> - first
> - second
>
> ```
> code block
> ```

---

As to why the blank line doesn't end the list, without the blank line the previous list item's paragraph is being continued:

```
 - list item
    New paragraph?
```

Renders to:

> - list item
>   New paragraph?

This allows you to have long list items in places where you want to hard wrap the lines.