# Bug in Stack Overflow Markdown rendering when code follows a list

Tags: bug, markdown, code, list

Code following a list, though not to be included in the list itself, is not correctly rendered, as shown below.

I have tried inserting linebreaks, to no avail.  Inserting "dummy" text will help the renderer.  Have I misunderstood the formatting?

---

The downvote as a duplicate is fair, as the original question is definitely the same.  I should have searched meta for this problem.

However-- many (appreciated) answers have explained various workarounds or manual spacing adjustments.  These suggestions overlook a problem I mentioned (in the comment in the sample code snippet): the `{}` (code) widget does not format the code (either as a list item or following the list) in this context.  This is, IMO, a UI/UX bug (confusion which lead to this post, obviously).  By comparison, if the `B` (bold) toolbar widget failed to bold the text in certain contexts, I think it would be recognized as a bug without much contention.

Here is a list.

1. One
2. Two
3. Three

   module Foo

   ## Not formatted as code, despite four space indentation *and* trying the `{}` widget.

   end

Here is another list.

1. One
2. Two

Inserting this text fixes the renderer.

```
module Foo
  # Now formatted as code.
end
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I did want to specify the language, so this is a fine workaround; it also means I don't need to indent when pasting +1.  I still think there is a bug lurking, because highlighting the text and using the `{}` toolbar widget *should* correctly format the code (however it wants to accomplish that, insert ```, or otherwise).

Comment: Does inserting a `<br>` fix the problem for you? That's HTML for a line break.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Markdown: Code directly after a list (and not as part of that list)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350701/markdown-code-directly-after-a-list-and-not-as-part-of-that-list)

Comment: @Mast It does, as does `<p>`, suggested elsewhere.  Although either must be preceded and followed by an empty line.  Lots of explanation provided in other answers and the FAQ, all of which I missed. :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's helpful, thank you, lots of good formatting information in the answers there.  I wish the `{}` widget button would simply do what it purports to do, however.

Comment: The `{}` button is really just an "indent everything in the selection by four spaces" button, which is sometimes _but not always_ the "code block" button.

Answer (score 7):

The system is unintuitive but I believe it works as designed. There’s a second meaning to indentation: “continue the list above” and this takes priority over indentation being interpreted as starting code.

You need to indent 8 spaces to get code in a list:

1. One
2. Two
3. Three

   ```
   module Foo
   ```

Alternatively, use a code fence (indent it all 4 spaces to make it part of the list, otherwise it’s just a regular code block):

1. One
2. Two
3. Three

   ```
   module Foo
   ```

---

Method 1:

```
 1. One
 2. Two
 3. Three

        module Foo
```

Method 2:

```
 1. One
 2. Two
 3. Three

    ~~~
    module Foo
    ~~~
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  Jeff provided a workaround elsewhere, which is enough I suppose.  I'm not going to play with all the spacing permutations.  I agree there is a question of whether or not the code is to be included in the list and the meaning of the spacing as attempting to decide that.  However, using the `{}` widget resulted in *no* code formatting whatsoever, either as a last list item or after the list.  IMO, I shouldn't need to twiddle spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try using 7 spaces:

1. One
2. Two
3. Three

   ```
   code
   ```

Or, as raw:

```
Try using 7 spaces:

1. One
2. Two
3. Three

       code
```

This lines the code up with the list. To "reset" it back to the left border, use a `<p>` element:

1. One
2. Two
3. Three

```
code
```

As raw:

```
1. One
2. Two
3. Three

<p>

    code
```

Alternatively, use three backticks at the start and end:

1. One
2. Two
3. Three

```
code
```

And, as raw:

````
1. One
2. Two
3. Three

```
code
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Bracket your code with lines of three backticks. If you specify the language on the first such line, you will also get syntax-based coloring for that language (in Stack Overflow).

1. List item One
2. List Item Two

````
Write-Host "This is an example of PowerShell code. In Stack Overflow, you'll get syntax coloring."
Write-Host "There is nothing but a single blank line between the list and ```powershell"
````