# I can't codify a piece of code, possible bug

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bug: code blocks after numbered or bulleted lists completely disappear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27243/bug-code-blocks-after-numbered-or-bulleted-lists-completely-disappear)

Sometimes I can't codify a piece of code, clicking on the two brackets { } at the top of the editor window.

Here's one example: 
[what should I do when I come across the error: invalid operands to binary & and error: invalid operands to binary |?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584428/what-should-i-do-when-i-come-across-the-error-invalid-operands-to-binary-and)

Please see my answer that contains code. I can't codify it properly.

Comment: Seems like  bug that that question made it through the quality filter.

Comment: @Bobby - the question has been edited.

Comment: @Bobby: Sadly, bad indentation is enough for that.

Answer (score 5):

There's a simply workaround: put `<!-->` after a list.

Did it for you in this specific case and it works perfectly.

Explanation is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27244/172552)

You can also indent by 8 spaces instead of 4

Comment: oh my, thanks, I will never ever remember the fix though :)