# Is this how Markdown should be rendering code inside a list?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

I believe the following example needs no explanation.

1. What is going on here?
2. Why would you do this?

   (function() {

   ```
   // Do Stuff
   ```

   })();

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25368/code-block-after-numbered-list-markdown-bug, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23822/markdown-code-block-problem, and probably others also.

Comment: I should have figured that something like this would have been spotted before. Although in my defense it is not immediately clear what search terms would find those duplicates.

Comment: Actually, it depends on whether you're trying to put the code into the list or right after it. If the former, then there is a different set of duplicates. And as for search terms, probably [markdown] [bug] would get you close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm note sure about what *should* happen (the [original markdown spec](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) leaves out all the edge cases), but I guess this is what you want:

1. What is going on here?
2. Why would you do this?

   ```
   (function() {

      // Do Stuff

   })();
   ```
3. All is back to good.

Just add another four spaces.

Comment: This is a workaround I can live with.

Answer (score 4):

see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

search for "skip a line and indent eight spaces" to see the example

1. What is going on here?
2. Why would you do this?

   ```
   (function() {        
       // Do Stuff       
    })();
   ```

Note that there is indeed a bug having to do with [blank lines inside code that is itself inside a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19624/markdown-formatting-bug-with-code-blocks-in-lists).