# How do I format this source code?

Tags: support, markdown, syntax-highlighting, code

I can't get it to look right!

See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1645999/list).

### Compare 1:

[code sample http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/1410/compare1.gif](http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/1410/compare1.gif)

---

[render sample http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/8014/compare1a.gif](http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/8014/compare1a.gif)

### Compare 2:

[code sample http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/3802/compare2.gif](http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/3802/compare2.gif)

---

[render sample http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/5982/compare2a.gif](http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/5982/compare2a.gif)

### Compare 3:

[code sample http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/5153/compare3.gif](http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/5153/compare3.gif)

---

[render sample http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/9646/compare3a.gif](http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/9646/compare3a.gif)

Comment: Hmm, I tried to reformat it and now `&lt;RemoteRequireHttps()&gt;` is getting escaped twice somehow.

Answer (score 3):

I was using a numbered list. I removed the list to fix the code.

More info and other fixes:  [Why is a code block not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/why-is-a-code-block-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-i)

Comment: +1 for looking at the example, which I failed to do....

Answer (score 2):

You need to indent **everything** in the code block by four spaces.

You're getting the code blocks that you are because the start and end lines are not indented by four spaces.  So add four spaces to the start of every line and it should work.

Comment: Because I was using a list, I needed to indent 8 spaces instead of four. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/why-is-a-code-block-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-i/11317#11317

Comment: Interesting....