# Code is indented by 4 spaces but isn't interpreted as code

Tags: support, markdown, syntax-highlighting, code, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is a code block not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/why-is-a-code-block-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-i)

If you look at my post ( 3rd down ) on [this stack overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440233/possible-to-intercept-and-rewrite-email-on-outlook-client-side-using-ironpython), you'll see that my code isn't highlighted.  Even though my code is indented by 4 spaces, I had to use the <PRE> tags around my code to get mono-space font.  If you take away the surrounding <PRE> tags, the code is interpreted as normal text, even though it is indented.

Comment: As Jon notes: this has to do with code following a list item. For more, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/why-is-a-code-block-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-i

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was in a list. In a list you have to indent it by 8 spaces.

Rich fixed this by adding a rule before the code, to effectively separate it from the list.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Perhaps the behavior of the "Code sample" button could be enhanced to do the 8 space indentation in the context of a list.  When I press the "code sample" button it only indents by 4-spaces.

Comment: or better yet, have the "code sample" button *always* indent 4 spaces on a press, instead of toggling the 4 spaces on or off.  then i can press it twice if i need the extra indentation.

Comment: @~quack - agreed (but there'd need to be an undo button, too).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: isn't that what Ctrl-Z is for?  :)  but yeah, a separate undo button would be ok.