# xxxx before code seems to be broken (4 spaces)

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

["Go To Definition" is greyed out but I can find variable via search in same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444269/go-to-definition-is-greyed-out-but-i-can-find-variable-via-search-in-same-file)

there are messages that say xxxx code
does not work with a list BUT
AFAIK I'm not having any list
at the above SO URL.

Please explain why the code snippets

```
internal protected bool Refreshing{  
get { return refreshing;}  
set { refreshing = value;}  
}
```

and

```
if (Refreshing) return;
```

do not show up as code both at SO
and here in *this* meta SO message.

thnx/g.

Comment: Uh... Not a question?

Comment: You need linebreaks between code segments and other elements of your post. For example, add another linebreak after "this code:" and "this statement:". This is a comment instead of an answer because this same question was asked within the past couple of weeks (with the very same "There's no lists!" part). Ah, [here it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58416/code-is-indented-4-spaces-but-is-not-interpreted-as-code-this-has-nothing-to-do).

Answer (score 3):

I added blank lines before your snippets (see my edit to your post). That will do the trick.

Comment: You probably should of put that in your answer instead of editing the question. Now the question does not make sense