# Question gets error: Please indent all code by 4 spaces

Tags: support, bug, markdown, code-formatting

My code is not in a list. I added an enter line before my code and indented by 4 spaces using `ctrl + K`, so why am I still getting this error: "Please indent all code by 4 spaces"?

[image]

My code registers as code in the preview of the question
[image]

I referenced [this question about formatting code NOT in a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58416/363976) and [this question about formatting code in a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)

Comment: I even tried attaching a screenshot of my code and got the same error. Pic: https://postimg.org/image/ftzbtlvuf/

Comment: @Gnemlock Pic: https://postimg.org/image/kqn7fri55/

Comment: I also wonder if the warning actually appears *directly at the questionable line*. Where you have `self.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage{#imageLiteral{resourceName: "SearchFieldBackground"), for: UIControlState.normal)`, could you move `"SearchFieldBackground"), for: UIControlState.normal)` to a separate line, and indent it further, as opposed to allowing word wrapping to move it to the next line?

Comment: Take special note of the position of the error; I believe, should this be the culprit, other lines will still flag the error; but you *should* notice that the position of the error display *moves*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the Stack Overflow Team and they told me, "The system sometimes picks up the image formatting erroneously when there are multiple images in a row." When I removed one image, I was able to post the question. Unfortunately, even when I tried to edit the question to include the removed image, I got the same error. Guess it's a glitch that Stackoverflow hasn't had time to fix ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Use a bulleted list format, or newlines in between.