# Can someone fix a truncated post?

Tags: support, specific-answer, character-limit, truncation

I am new to Stack Overflow, so I have no reputation.  I am trying to view a post that I think has been truncated.  [Here's a link to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686452/create-wcf-service-for-unmanaged-c-clients/687717#687717).  It explains how to create a C# client for a WCF service and then use that client in C++ through a bridge.  However, the end of the post says:

> In the Solution Explorer, right-click the References folder for the HelloServiceClient project and select the Add Service Reference... menu option. In the Address field, type the

I'm assuming there is supposed to be more there that I cannot see.  I found a post that I think explains how to fix this problem (I can't link to this post because I can only have 1 link since I have no reputation).  It says:

> The revision history will contain the actual post in any case, so doing an edit no-op (inserting a space) will restore the truncated content.

I would try this fix myself, but I cannot edit someone else's post because I have no reputation.  So...  I'm wondering if someone else out there could perform the fix on that post so that I can see the rest of the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, although there is a bunch of code blocks contained in the lists which don't format correctly. I had to [add a hack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/why-is-a-code-block-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-i/3331#3331) to get the code formatted properly.

Comment: Add 4 more indents for the code.

Comment: I think we had an edit collision. You may want to double check that it is right.

Comment: OK, That post is *not* cooperating. I tried rolling back to your better edit and it didn't seem to do it. I'm at a loss. :(