# Suggestion: fix truncation of long posts by re-rendering markdown to HTML on very old posts

Tags: discussion, bug, status-declined, markdown

It seems like bug reports about truncated posts [come](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36418/minor-formatting-bug) [up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35742/there-appears-to-be-another-formatting-leak) [a](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26721/long-answers-are-truncated-in-so) [lot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34956/can-someone-fix-a-truncated-post) on Meta. (And those are just four that I found in a quick search, I know there are more.) It all goes back to [a bug on the server-side markdown-rendering code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/serverfault-cut-off-truncated-on-long-post) from way back in Fall of 2008. (*Edit: looks like it was a little more recent than that.*) The bug manifests itself in obviously-truncated posts, or posts where formatting from the post "leaks" to the "edit | flag" links. There are still some rogue posts which haven't been edited in over a year that have this problem.

I propose that the team solve this problem at the source, by re-rendering the markdown to HTML and invalidate the cache for all posts with a last-edit date before 2009-01-01. (*Edit: or whenever the bug was fixed.*). I can't imagine that there are *that* many posts which haven't been touched in over a year, and you could do it in a batch process during off-peak hours.

Comment: Hmmm, tried to comment on Chet A aka Rich B's answer that got downvoted, but it's gone. Anyway: that old bug is described at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/serverfault-cut-off-truncated-on-long-post

Comment: @ArjanvanBentem: thanks, I added that link to the text

Comment: They could just throw out any cached HTML that hasn't been used for 6 months. It may not work, but it could at least reduce the size of the database. ( Not that it needs it though )

Answer (score 1):

Too much work for not enough benefit. Easier to just fix them as they come up.