# Syntax highlighting broken after numbered list

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is a code block not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/why-is-a-code-block-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-i)

The 4 space indent is not being recognized as a code block after a numbered list.

See below for example:

1. Make waffle batter
2. Cook for 6 to 8 weeks
3. Feed to unicorn

   public void EatWaffles(Unicorn unicorn)
   {
       if (unicorn.LikesWaffles)
       {
           // do something
       }
   }

First saw the problem on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669943/list-view-new-line-for-new-values/2670019#2670019).  I forced the code highlighting on that answer using <pre><code>...</code></pre>, but I think this is probably a problem that should be fixed.

Comment: You might want to switch the order of those ending tags. Generally it would be `</code></pre>`

Comment: @Chacha102: Oops! Since I had to add the &lt; and &gt; to make the tags show, I copied and pasted it but forgot to reverse the order.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Indent your code eight spaces instead of four.

- I
- Am
- a
- List!

  ```
  public class OhLookImAfterAList
  {
      public OhLookImAfterAList()
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Oh Snap!");
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Hmmm...I wonder if the code formatting button should be modified to add the 8 spaces if the block is just after a list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put 8 spaces for that.