# Code after bulleted lists

Tags: support, markdown

> Related (but not the same issue): [Markdown formatting bug with code blocks in lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19624/markdown-formatting-bug-with-code-blocks-in-lists)
>
> Duplicate: [Why is a code block not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/why-is-a-code-block-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-i)

The formatting guide says that you should indent code 4 spaces.  However in this answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813426/asp-classic-include-once/2916661#2916661) is not working correctly.  The problem seems to be when code *directly* follows, but is not part of a bulleted list.

I have replicated the bug below.  Inserting a character between the end of the bullet and the code will cause it to appear correctly.  See the second section for an example.

This seems to occur in both the preview and the posting.

---

- List

  with new Importer
      .import "foo"
      .import "bar/baz"
  end with

---

- List

Text

```
with new Importer
    .import "foo"
    .import "bar/baz"
end with
```

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47326/syntax-highlighting-broken-after-numbered-list-closed

Comment: @Jeff Atwood Isn't this what the `status-bydesign` tag is for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is a code block not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/why-is-a-code-block-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-i)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a list, you need to indent the code by 8 spaces rather than 4.

After a list, if you really don't want to have text before some more code, you can use something like `&nbsp;` to fake it:

- List item

  ```
  Code within item
  ```
- Next item

```
Code after the list
```

In general though, I'd suggest including some text to introduce the code after the list anyway, which works round the problem.

Comment: It is documented for (ordered) lists, in item 4 in "Advanced lists: Nesting".

Comment: @KennyTM: Ah, yes. Will edit...

Comment: @Jon It's not supposed to be in the list, it's supposed to be after the list.

Comment: @C. Ross: Ah. The title confused me, and I see that was Jeff's edit. I suggest you edit the question to be somewhat clearer.

Comment: It's not "simply" eight spaces. It's 4 spaces plus 4 per indentation level :) (for when you nest lists)

Comment: An HTML comment would actually be cleaner than using a dummy string like &nbsp. It counts as real enough to constitute content for separating the list from the code, but since it is a comment it is skipped so you don't end up with a huge gap between the two.