# Code is not formatted in this answer

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616924/how-to-check-if-the-key-pressed-was-an-arrow-key-in-java-keylistener/617004#617004) is not formatted even though it has 4 spaces identation.

Comment: I've noticed this also. It seems to occur when the code block follows a numbered list. See another example in the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336443/geodjango-importing-data-from-osgb-1936-displaying-in-wgs84

Answer (score 4):

```
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
     int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
     switch( keyCode ) { 
         case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
             // handle up 
             break;
         case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
             // handle down 
             break;
         case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
             // handle left
             break;
         case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
             // handle right
             break;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Here's what the answer originally looked like.  Go to the edit screen to see the broken formatting.

Comment: It looks right in the preview...

Comment: I wonder if those spaces aren't you run-of-the-mill space.

Comment: @jjnguy: Just checked, they're all your standard `U+0020` spaces. :/

Answer (score 3):

Weird.  It had 5 spaces of indentation and a single empty (except for the indentation) line at the beginning.  When I removed those, it fixed the formatting.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what was broken here nor when it got fixed, but it works correctly now (I tried [Bill's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58039/code-not-formatted-in-this-answer/58047#58047) on a dev build, and it renders correctly).

Comment: Have you forgotten to deploy that change?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: You said that it look fixed now. It isn'T.

Comment: If someone made a dummy edit to Bill's answer, it would be [rendered correctly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/58047/revisions). I just didn't do that to preserve history.

Comment: Okay, that seems fair. Sorry for bothering

Comment: i can't seem to comment on my answer that you deleted below, so i'll comment here. i just faced the same problem mentioned in this question in an answer i posted on stack overflow. it wouldnt format code which followed a numbered list. i thought my answer below was helpful in that if you follow those steps it fixes the problem of code not being formatted as code when it follows a numbered list.

Comment: @vikrantislav: That has nothing to do with *this* question though, that's why I deleted your answer. For what it's worth, there is  a question (actually there are several questions) about your topic as well; see my explanation at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item/99637#99637