# Why is this code not displayed as code even though it appears to be formatted correctly?

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting

Why isn't [Date Sudhir Baban's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/java-swing-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel/4050268#4050268) (screen dump below) displayed as code even though it seems to be formatted correctly - 4 spaces indent for each line?

[image: Screen dump of code not display as code even though it seems to be formatted correctly.]

---

The source is displayed below. The grey dots are space and verified to be ASCII code 32; TABs would display in a different way.

[image]

A similar issue with 4-spaces-indented code was *[Code not formatted in this answer:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58039/code-not-formatted-in-this-answer)*, but it was supposedly resolved and fixed.

Comment: Whoops, I fixed it...

Comment: Odd, I rolled back to his original revision, and it was still fixed.

Comment: I think there used to be a bug when a post started with code.

Comment: @jjnguy: perhaps the HTML is cached somewhere and any old post needs to be refreshed to display correctly after the fix?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's right. (@mmy, @ Peter)

Comment: Yes, the HTML is created from the Markdown at submission/rollback time; the revisions store only the Markdown. So if a bug is fixed in the Markdown parser, this doesn't reflect until the post is edited.