# What changed in this revision?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, edits, code-formatting, revisions-list

I noticed that a post had a formatting issue (code appeared to not be indented). I opened the editor, and curiously enough the code seemed fine in the preview without me having to make any changes, so I just hit "Save Edits". The new revision has the proper formatting, but according to [the revision page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/442549/revisions), I didn't change anything in terms of the post source; the indents appear to have already been in the first revision.

I looked at [Data Explorer's snapshot of the post](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/117727/) from earlier this month and it seems to have this for the body:

```
<p>_targetForm.dw_retailer.SetColumn(6);
    _targetForm.dw_retailer.SetText(retailer.text);
    _targetForm.dw_retailer.SetColumn(9);
    _targetForm.dw_retailer.SetText(retailer.webname);</p>
...
```

Whereas if I view the page source, I see this:

```
<pre><code>_targetForm.dw_retailer.SetColumn(6);
_targetForm.dw_retailer.SetText(retailer.text);
_targetForm.dw_retailer.SetColumn(9);
_targetForm.dw_retailer.SetText(retailer.webname);
</code></pre>
...
```

What happened here? Did I trigger some sort of automated, silent, retroactive edit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that this post is very old; it was posted in January of 2009. Since then, many bugs have been fixed in our Markdown implementation, but a post is only ever rendered when it's posted or edited; the rendered version is then stored (otherwise, we'd have to re-render every post on every pageview).

So when you made that null-edit, you just forced a re-rendering, and since the bug has since been fixed, it now looks correct. Because the revision list always renders posts with the *current* Markdown version (only the most current revision is stored as cooked HTML), it looks like nothing has changed, as the *old* revision is rendered with the *current* implementation.

Other examples of this phenomenon include [Answer Layout Bug in IE9/Chrome - Footer Encapsulated In Code Block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104725/answer-layout-bug-in-ie9-chrome-footer-encapsulated-in-code-block) and [Code is not formatted in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58039/code-is-not-formatted-in-this-answer) (the latter looks very similar to issue you encountered).