# Why wasn't this code formatted correctly?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is a code block not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/why-is-a-code-block-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-i)

Why did this line of code:

```
} elseif(preg_match("/(mysql_num_rows()|mysql_fetch_array()|Error Occured While Processing Request|error in your sql syntax|mysql_fetch_row()|VBScript Runtime|BOF or EOF|mysql_fetch_object()|Invalid Querystring/i", Connect_Host(str_replace("=", "='", $sites[2][$a]))))) {
```

not format correctly [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659779/can-i-use-elseif-with-preg-match-in-php/6659828#6659828), but work correctly here on Meta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it was included immediately following a **bulleted list**, the markdown parser made it *part* of that bulleted list. Notice how it was indented and how it lines up with the bulleted text:

[image]

In order to indicate that code blocks in a bulleted list should be formatted as code, you need to indent lines with **eight (8)** spaces, rather than the usual four (4). After you do that, everything works fine.

And of course, the reason it worked fine with only 4 spaces here on Meta is because there are no bullets in your question.

(See also: [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/why-is-a-code-block-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-i))