# Why does code formatting for XML fail here?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

The first two XML examples in the question [How to get the default value from an XmlSchema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262884/how-to-get-the-default-value-from-an-xmlschema/6303179) seem to not get rendered as code blocks at all (after being revised by someone). The third XML example renders fine.

All requirements to render as an XML code block (to my knowledge) seem to be fulfilled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sixth edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6262884/6) caused the code blocks to appear under actual ordered list items, instead of just normal paragraphs. Once that happened, the four space indentation was [no longer sufficient](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item/99637#99637) for the Markdown parser to consider it to be code.

It's [since been fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6262884/7) by turning the ordered list items back into paragraphs that start with numbers (which made a little more sense in this case anyway, due to the other text interrupting the numbering), but the code formatting issue would also have been resolved using one of the following Markdown snippets:

```
1. List item

        <code>
```

or

```
1. List item

<!-- --->

    <code>
```

Comment: damn TIM ! You were 5 seconds faster, it's different solution though :)

Comment: Great link to the other Question. Now it's blatantly obvious why it failed :)