# Four space indented code cannot immediately succeed a numbered list in markdown

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)

The title says it all. Here is a reproduction:

1. An Item
2. A second item

   // Note that there are four lines of whitespace between the setence and this code
   public void main() {
       printf("Hello World!");
   }

Now that same code under a regular paragraph:

```
public void main() {
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: See my explanation in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item/99637#99637

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you want the code to be indented, do it like this:

   ```
   // four more spaces
   public void main() {
     printf("Hello World!");
   }
   ```
2. If it's outside the list, then like that:

```
void foo() {
  bar();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You simply need extra more four spaces:

1. An Item
2. A second item

   ```
   // Note that there are four lines of whitespace between the setence and this code
   public void main() {
       printf("Hello World!");
   }
   ```

Not sure what's the reason, but it's been like that always.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a bug. A 4-space intend after a numbered list is used to have multi-paragraph numbered items. For example:

1. My first item.
2. My second item.

   A bit more about my second item.
3. My third item.

You can always use explicit HTML-style markup to start a code block. Or you can put a comment between the last item and the code block.