# Bug: Code formatting doesn't work when it's preceded by bulleted/numbered list

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)

As subject says. Example:

- code not formatted
- if it's after bulleted list

  code1
  code2

  2. code not formatted
  3. if it is
  4. after numbered list

  code1
  code2

Formatting works after normal text

```
code1
code2
```

Answer (score 1):

- The following code should be highlighted just fine

  ```
  print "I am code"
  ```
- (code was indented with 8 spaces)