# Implement ```-style (fenced) Markdown code blocks

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, markdown-rendering

Currently, Stack Exchange’s Markdown parser only allows four-space indents to represent code blocks:

```
    // some code
    // another line of code
```

[GitHub Flavored Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/) and other Markdown implementations allow for an alternative syntax, that doesn’t require indenting each code line:

````
```
// some code
// another line of code
```
````

This is much more convenient to type out. It would be super useful if Stack Exchange could support this syntax.

---

By extension, this syntax also allow you to specify the source language right after the opening ```` ``` ````:

````
```js
// some code
// another line of code
```
````

…which would then enable syntax highlighting for that specific language. Although it’s interesting metadata, I don’t think this feature is needed on Stack Overflow, as the syntax highlighting library works pretty well for various languages.

So, even if you would allow this syntax but ignore the ```` ```language ````, this would greatly improve my productivity on Stack Exchange.

## What do you think?

The moderators are currently collecting feedback regarding this feature, so **please post a comment with your thoughts**. Good idea? Bad idea? Don’t really care? What do you think are the benefits/drawbacks? Experiences? Let them know! Thanks!

Comment: +1 I think this would be great. Not having to worry about an extra 4-space indent when editing code the textbox would make it less necessary to pull it out into an external editor and then paste it back in.

Comment: @cdeszaq I should note that there is a button in the WMD Editor to turn the selection into a block of code (by indenting each line with 4 spaces), but still — selecting the text + hitting the button or even typing the keyboard shortcut takes much longer than simply typing the opening and closing backticks.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this, but for editing existing code, it would make things easier.

Comment: Sadly, not many people who mistakenly use backticks for multiline code blocks delimit them with three consecutive backticks. Like this idea though!

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: This feature wouldn't be intended for people who accidentally stumble across it, but for people who actually *know* it's there and find it is a more convenient method of posting code than indenting by four spaces (I would probably use it).

Comment: This is a reasonable suggestion, we're considering it. A nice side effect would be that this kind of code block wouldn't have a ["placed after a list"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item/99637#99637) problem.

Comment: When adding it, please consider handling four-backtick "fences" just like the regular three-backtick fences. On a German keyboard it's extremely annoying to enter an odd number of backticks since it's a deadkey and you cannot change it without [side-effects](http://superuser.com/questions/282471/ctrlshiftf-not-working-in-putty-when-using-a-modified-keyboard-layout-on-win-7).

Comment: @Tom: selecting code and pressing Ctrl+K (or the `{}` button in editor toolbar) seems easier than typing backticks six times at two different places.

Comment: I didn't know about dead keys before reading ThiefMaster's comment. Here's a [convenient link to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) for others who need a quick overview.

Comment: It's essentially possible to do this already (you can specify a code language) by just typing it out and then selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K (or clicking the code button), but this would greatly simplify the process.

Comment: @Chichiray: Clicking is easier than dragging as the latter requires you to aim such that you select the text right, and `\`` is a single key where Ctrl+K is not; as a result `click \`\`\`  click \`\`\`` is faster to perform.

Comment: I can't count how many times I've gone through and put 4 spaces on the clipboard, then flew down the lines of code repeatedly hitting `Ctrl+V, DownArrow, Home` to indent the entire block.

Comment: @gobernador what text editor are you using?, it is usually possible to indent the whole thing if it is selected and then insert some tabs. Or in the editor of this site, just select the whole thing and click the 'code' icon and will indent for you

Comment: @balpha: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/10/the-future-of-markdown.html

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail I'm well aware of that :)

Comment: @gobernador you poor poor man. How have you not heard of regex NOR the alt-shift method in Windows? (since most of us use Windows) where you can use Notepad++ and alt-shift to block select a range of text (say for deleting column formated text, or inserting a string of spaces to the front of the text)

Comment: @ThiefMaster on the US International keyboard I have the same problem, but you could type `tilde tilde tilde <space>` to get 3 tildes.  That said, supporting an arbitrary number of tildes would be the best solution.

Comment: Fenced code blocks are less readable _in raw_, IMHO. Especially in larger texts.  
Having said that, in online posts convenience of input outweighs raw appearance by a lot. And the texts are quite short.

So:  
- Fenced - for online posts, it's convenient to write
- Indented - for files, it's more readable in raw

I vote for the triple tildes/backticks, that is.

Comment: Would be awesome. I'm craving for this a long time!

Comment: #1 feature for me, because pasting long blocks of logs/code/stacktraces is annoying without being able to do this. backticks, tildes I don't care, just give me a non indented format

Comment: there's a [spec](http://jgm.github.io/stmd/spec.html#fenced-code-blocks) already, I hope you can find time implementing this.

Comment: @balpha Given [this syntax is now standardized in CommonMark](https://jgm.github.io/stmd/spec.html#fenced-code-blocks), could this be reconsidered?

Comment: @MathiasBynens Yep: https://twitter.com/balpha/status/509268034134224896. I just can't promise when I'll get to it.

Comment: I think this would be a fantastic addition and make it easier for sites that are code-heavy, which is a good bit of the bigger sites. Please implement this!

Comment: Updated link to the CommonMark spec (old URLs are broken): http://spec.commonmark.org/

Comment: The new Documentation system (currently in private beta) is using a different, CommonMark-based parser with support for fenced code blocks. Documentation should be out of beta within a month or two. Maybe we'll see that parser used elsewhere on the site, after it's been exercised for a little while.

Comment: This has taken so long and is so annoying! Please, it doesn't need to be to CommonMark spec, just add triple-backticks.

Comment: @jeremyBanks please update the group re: status of this feature. You said a month or two 6 months ago

Comment: @jcollum Please note that I made that comment before I was an employee (or even planning to apply); it was just uninformed speculation. I'll see if there's any information I can now share, but I haven't yet looked into this issue since I started.

Comment: It's not much in terms of import but this is my absolute #1 feature request for SO. Like the only thing I can think of that I care about.

Comment: I am wondering what's the reason for making this deferred, maybe a little bit of NIH syndrome? This was a very popular request, easy to implement and low risk. Why not spending 100x more effort on experimenting new ways of writing and hosting documentation.

Comment: This feature would be fantastic. I abhor spaces for indentation, and don't like having to use them in my posts—but even if I could use tabs, I still much prefer the `\`\`\`` syntax.

Comment: Most of the comments here are about how easy or difficult it is for the person commenting to enter. I don’t care about that so much; I know enough tricks that I can get the indentation right, and if I’m worried I check the preview. However, *people new to the site* don’t know this. At *least* half the questions on SO with code blocks have bad indentation, and this is especially visible in the python tag. Right now I’m trying to answer a question when I don’t know what the code actually says because of inconsistent indentation, and I am *not* inclined to blame the asker for that.

Comment: I'll buy the Stack Overflow engineers a beer (or more) for fixing this. 

When writing code on Stack Overflow, I often write it in my editor and copy it over into the answer. It's a horrible experience that I hope can be fixed. 

PLEASE!

Comment: I wish, I wish this would come to be.

Comment: i'll just leave this here ;) *"as a social phenomenon, this philosophy can manifest as an unwillingness to adopt an idea or product because it originates from another culture, a form of tribalism"* — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here

Comment: @balpha [this fork](https://github.com/KyleGobel/MarkdownSharp-GithubCodeBlocks) of MarkdownSharp (which I believe is what StackExchange uses?) has implemented this feature, maybe that could be used? Pretty please? https://i.imgur.com/LOeGj.gif

Comment: Amazing that this hasn't been implemented, but it also seems (with zero knowledge of what's required, of course!) that it would be straightforward to create a light chrome extension that would allow you to input github flavored markdown and convert what you've entered into SO-style markdown when you hit publish or preview or something. Anyone know of anything like that?

Comment: Aaand it did turn out to be easy! I made a chrome extension to fix this. Hope this helps! https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/weirdify-markdown/chbodjbichobmpllbdnoeegaoblholpm

Answer (score 197, accepted):

## Code fences work now.

```js
function DeepThought(task) {
    this.task = task;
}
DeepThought.prototype.answer = function () {
    switch (this.task) {
        case "life, universe, and everything": return 42;
        default: throw "not implemented";
    }
}
```

([view source on this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/d29ee470-c239-4d38-8ab1-5583517d1f9c/view-source))

As much as that's possible for a partial feature, they are compliant with [CommonMark 0.28](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#fenced-code-blocks). That means:

- A code fence consists of three or more backticks ```` ``` ```` or tildes `~~~`, indented by zero to three spaces.
- The opening fence can be followed by a [syntax indicator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109). On Stack Exchange, this can be a Prettify module name (e.g. ```` ```lang-cxx ````) or a tag for which syntax highlighting has been configured (e.g. ```` ```c++ ````). ```` ```none ```` disables syntax highlighting.
- The closing code fence needs to use the same character, and at least the same number as the opening code fence.
- The code block will be de-dented by as many spaces as the opening code fence was indented with. So this:

  ```
  See this:
    ~~~
    foo
      bar
    ~~~
  ```

  turns into this:

  > See this:
  >
  > ```
  > foo
  >   bar
  > ```
- An unclosed fenced codeblock continues to the end of the block (e.g. block quote) or post.

That last point is also the reason for the only real edge case breakage that this causes with existing content. If somebody created a horizontal line in a post with something like `~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`, that is now going to open a code block. As always when we make markdown changes, the question & answer view is not going to be impacted by this unless the post is edited, and it's extremely rare, so I'm not too worried about this.

Comment: Wow, cool! You folks are on fire this week.

Comment: @JoshCaswell 10th Anniversary affect.

Comment: Hi balpha. When are we going to change help information? E.g. the "How to format" on the right side of asking a question etc.

Comment: I have just updated [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/4642212).

Comment: We should also update the “indent all code with 4 spaces” error. It likely won’t trigger on triple-backtick fences, but will it trigger on `~~~` fences? Also, it should mention fenced code blocks as an alternative.

Comment: @Xufox Good call on the "unformatted code" detector. Fix for that is in the pipeline. As for the other thing, there are a bunch of places where indenting is recommended. Once code fences have been working for a bit, we may revisit which way of creating code blocks should be the recommended one.

Comment: I just told someone that triple backticks don't work on main, then had to eat my words when I tried and it worked. Could you guys please feature this post or fire up a separate announcement? Considering the large previously-malformed-but-now-valid post rate, this is important information. Also thanks.

Comment: Why did you decide to require e.g. ```lang-js``` instead of just ```js``` like other common implementations of fenced code blocks?

Comment: @MathiasBynens That's how it's always been when you specify the syntax highlighting language on SO, so that's what I went with for my example. You can leave off the `lang-`, that's going to work as well.

Comment: I just noticed this accidentally—7 days after the fact. For a moment I thought I had gone crazy—“why is my GFM suddenly valid on SO!?!?”

Comment: [Another victim](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21927834). (Someone trying to change working formatting to equivalent working formatting; can't be due to anything other than lack of information.)

Answer (score 170):

### Benefits

- Compatibility with [GitHub-Flavored Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/) and other Markdown libraries that support this *de facto* standard ([and possibly its variants](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143705/131916)). This enables copy-pasting from gists or Markdown files within repositories, which can be useful on programming-related sites like Stack Overflow.
- The triple backtick syntax is easier and faster to type than indenting each line of code with four spaces.
- Saves some storage in the database, too! ;)

All the above benefits apply to the new syntax, even without the additional functionality to specify the programming language. With that functionality, I’ll add another (huge) benefit:

- As it’s much easier to specify the language of code blocks using this syntax (compared to [the current syntax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125209/131916)), I wouldn’t be surprised if this change caused more people to explicitly declare the programming language, so that the syntax highlighting can be more accurate. This is useful for answers that include, e.g. separate HTML and CSS code blocks.

### Drawbacks

I honestly can’t think of any. It’s very likely no one is using the triple backtick-syntax at the moment as it doesn’t work; so I doubt it will break anything. If you don’t like the new syntax, feel free to stick to the old one.

### Experiences

Ever since GitHub enabled this syntax, I’ve grown accustomed to it. I ♥ triple backtick syntax, and every time I’m forced to go back to the four-space-indent syntax, it feels awkward.

Comment: 159 places have a triple-backtick (I was scared to search for a double-backtick, though): http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/76842 As far as I can tell, none of them would be broken by implementing this.

Comment: @minitech Thanks for the query. I see a few that might cause problems, but with just 159 results it's not beyond the realm of possibility to manually verify that each one is correct, or is fixed, if this were implemented.

Comment: @Servy I would even volunteer to manually verify these if it meant getting this feature!

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I'd help!

Answer (score 81):

I don't really care either way whether this gets implemented: it's a superfluous extension to Markdown (unlike, say, inline HTML, spoiler markdown, or the as-yet-unimplemented-on-Stack-Exchange table syntax), but it is true the fenced code block has been added to pretty much every Markdown library that doesn't stick to just the original spec.

However, the triple backtick syntax is a *GitHub* extension, and it's not exactly the "de facto standard" [Mathias Bynens portrays it as](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142862/149432).

Fenced code blocks, as far as I understand it, were first introduced in [the PHP Markdown Extra library](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#fenced-code-blocks) as the following:

> Fenced code blocks are like Markdown’s regular code blocks, except that they’re not indented and instead rely on a start and end fence lines to delimit the code block. The code block start with a line containing three or more tilde ~ characters, and ends with the first line with the same number of tilde ~. For instance:
>
> ```
> This is a paragraph introducing:
>
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> a one-line code block
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

Other implementations followed suit, by either supporting only 3+ tildes or supporting both 3+ tildes and 3+ backticks. I ran through the implementations I know of, and [Wikipedia's (incomplete) list of implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Markdown_implementations) (before GitHub went down), and found:

#### Supports only the 3+ tilde syntax:

- [PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/)
- [Python Markdown](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/fenced_code_blocks/)
- [Discount](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/%7Eorc/Code/discount/)
- [Pegdown](https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown)

#### Supports only the triple backtick syntax:

- [ByWord](http://bywordapp.com)
- [Elements](http://www.secondgearsoftware.com/elements/)
- [PEG Markdown Highlight](http://hasseg.org/peg-markdown-highlight) (and derivative [Qarkdown](http://hasseg.org/hgweb/qarkdown))
- [R Markdown](http://www.rstudio.org/docs/r_markdown) (only documents triple backtick, but based on Sundown, which supports both)
- [markdown-clj](https://github.com/yogthos/markdown-clj)
- [Showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown)

#### Supports both:

- The [CommonMark specification](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#fenced-code-blocks)
- [Marked App](http://markedapp.com/help/Special_Features/For_Programmers.html)
- [Sundown](https://github.com/vmg/sundown) (and derivative [Redcarpet](https://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet))
- [GitHub](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/) (only documents the triple backtick, but parses both just fine)
- [Blackfriday](https://github.com/russross/blackfriday)
- [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html)
- [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)
- [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org)
- [Markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it)

#### Supports neither, or is unspecified:

- [mm2pdf](http://code.google.com/p/mmd2pdf/)
- [peg-markdown](https://github.com/jgm/peg-markdown) and [peg-multimarkdown](https://github.com/dtjm/peg-multimarkdown)
- MarkdownSharp
- [libupskirt](https://github.com/siuying/libupskirt)
- [MarkdownJ](http://markdownj.org)
- [MarkdownPapers](http://markdown.tautua.org)
- [Txtmark](https://github.com/rjeschke/txtmark)
- [Pagedown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/)
- [Dillinger](http://dillinger.io) (treats triple backtick code blocks as inline code)

Based on this, I think Stack Exchange should support the tilde syntax, the triple backtick syntax, and the 3+ backtick syntax. Bonus: support of either the tilde syntax or the 3+ backtick syntax should solve [the deadkey problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-markdown-code-blocks/143705#comment367824_125148%5D).

The syntax toolbar should continue to indent code with 4 spaces as per the original Markdown spec, or if that's not feasible, it should use the tilde syntax, which has the benefits of being the original version, compatible with GitHub, and marginally more supported by existing implementations.

Comment: Excellent research! Good point about supporting all variants of the syntax to eliminate the _dead key_ problem.

Comment: Thanks for the great research. I'm still not 100% sure we should do it, but this answer contains excellent information to base a decision on.

Comment: «Bonus: support of either the tilde syntax or the 3+ backtick syntax should solve the deadkey problem.»: while I agree with you say, this last one is false. In my standard Portuguese keyboard, both `` ` `` and `~` are deadkeys.

Comment: Both tilde and backtick is dead keys on Swedish keyboards too.

Comment: @JMCF125: And what happens if you press the dead key twice? Yep, it acts as if it was not dead, twice.

Comment: @user149432, The thing is that Github is 90% of the population, so if Github supports it....

Comment: Yeah I have to agree with @Pacerier. Listing the libraries like this makes it seem like `~` and ``` are equally popular. In reality Github is *huge*, and not all libraries are equally popular.

Comment: Doxygen supports the tilde and the backtick syntax

Comment: The deadkey problem links back to this answer. intended?

Comment: the dead key shouldn't be too much of a problem unless the kb layout is b0rken - typing the dead key twice should result in one character. And yes, the Finnish layouts share these 2 with the Swedish ones ([but we've got one layout with gazillion dead keys more as well](http://jkorpela.fi/nappis.gif))

Answer (score 55):

On Stack Overflow, all the time I'm seeing this happen to people who don't know the syntax.

class Foo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // y my code no is working
    Sytem.out.println(qrew3r);
}
```

}

Some people stop there and never fix it because it's close enough. Others figure out that the first and last lines aren't part of the code block because they're not indented. So they indent those two lines - only those two lines - because the editor doesn't provide an apparent way to indent the whole block.

```
class Foo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // y my code no is working
    Sytem.out.println(qrew3r);
}
}
```

The result is that we have a site that systematically causes newbs to post questions with poorly-formatted code. Whether or not you like fenced code blocks, when you look at all of the mistakes that users are making, you've got to appreciate that the current UX is broken.

Comment: ..."the editor doesn't provide an apparent way to indent the whole block". There is, though not apparent: `Ctrl` + `k` after you select the block. (On Mac it's `⌘` + `k`)

Comment: @FranklinYu ooh, I did not know that. Thanks.

Comment: It’s even worse in Python, where you often literally cannot tell what the code is supposed to do. In brace-delimited languages you can work past the bad formatting.

Comment: yes, this is really annoying and unintuitive. I have to google on how to fix this and goes back to StackOverflow to write an answer. The problem will grow bigger when combining with a list and long lines of code.

Answer (score 15):

Another reason to include this syntax: Some people are already using it.

However, it makes their posts look kind of strange, since it becomes inline code spread over multiple lines:

`This is what it looks like
when you put triple backticks above and below
multiple lines of text.`

```
By contrast, this is 
a multi-line code block
created by indenting text four spaces.
```

Comment: On 10 million questions the numbers are rather low: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/488893?year=-1

Comment: @rene What if you add old revisions that people have fixed in the meantime?

Comment: @Gilles uuugghh, that will probably kill SEDE ;) I'll give it a try later

Comment: @rene Does your query account for every version in a post's history? I find and fix triple-backtick posts to proper syntax all the time, and I wonder if the "low" number is only low due to human effort. Personally, I don't mind doing it, but if I and others no longer needed to fix these posts, we could use that time for something more useful.

Comment: @DanLowe no that query didn't take posthistory into account. [This one](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/615903?start=2016-01-01&end=2016-07-31) does but I limited both the date range as well as the number of rows because the full table scan on the posthistory table is killing the performance and it timesout if I fetch much more rows.

Answer (score 14):

You can currently [specify a language](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to be syntax-highlighted.

Example:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    //JS code...
```

This should not discourage the question, it is even a *plus* because they don't need to code this feature anymore.

The only thing left to do is to implement the ```` code blocks system (which I believe, is not that hard)

Comment: Good to know — thanks! Sounds like a regular expression that converts the triple backtick-syntax into the existing syntax behind the curtains could be a quick fix.

Comment: This is not as nice than the triple-backtick syntax though.

Comment: github supports the same using ```php for example

Comment: @ThiefMaster, Exactly. This is a bother to type (or even to use the UI), often I just don't bother and do it the "old way".

Comment: This `<!-- language: lang-js -->` is horrific! I always need to go Google to remember the exact syntax

Answer (score 13):

Another major benefit is when marking down code within lists. Creating block codes within list is often a major annoyance, contrast:

```
- Bullet 1

 Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 1).

 Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 2).

        var foo1 = bar1;
        var foo2 = bar2;
        var foo3 = bar3;

 Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 3).
```

to:

````
- Bullet 1

 Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 1).

 Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 2).
```javascript
var foo1 = bar1;
var foo2 = bar2;
var foo3 = bar3;
```

 Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 3).
````

Bulk of the annoyance comes from the editor not being able to do 8-space indents as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> un-indents instead of converting four spaces to eight. *"Also, is that blank gap 7 spaces or 9 spaces?"*

Of course, the problem is magnified when trying to put block codes within nested lists. Contrast:

```
- Bullet 1
 - Bullet 1.1

     Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 1).

     Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 2).

            var foo1 = bar1;
            var foo2 = bar2;
            var foo3 = bar3;

     Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 3).
```

to:

````
- Bullet 1
  - Bullet 1.1

   Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 1).

   Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 2).
```javascript
var foo1 = bar1;
var foo2 = bar2;
var foo3 = bar3;
```

   Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 3).
````

It gets worse with double nested lists. Contrast:

```
- Bullet 1
 - Bullet 1.1
     - Bullet 1.1.1

         Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 1).

         Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 2).

                var foo1 = bar1;
                var foo2 = bar2;
                var foo3 = bar3;

         Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 3).
```

to:

````
- Bullet 1
  - Bullet 1.1
   - Bullet 1.1.1

     Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 1).

     Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 2).
```javascript
var foo1 = bar1;
var foo2 = bar2;
var foo3 = bar3;
```

     Lorem Ipsum (paragraph 3).
````

Hopefully inserting block codes within list will be less time-consuming after the update.

Answer (score 7):

Another (very) minor benefit is that you can use this syntax to break up code blocks.  For example, this code ([rendered in an engine](https://markdown-it.github.io/#md3=%7B%22source%22%3A%22%60%60%60%5Cnblock1%5Cn%60%60%60%5Cn%60%60%60%5Cnblock2%5Cn%60%60%60%5Cn%60%60%60%5Cnblock3%5Cn%60%60%60%5Cn%22%2C%22defaults%22%3A%7B%22html%22%3Afalse%2C%22xhtmlOut%22%3Afalse%2C%22breaks%22%3Afalse%2C%22langPrefix%22%3A%22language-%22%2C%22linkify%22%3Atrue%2C%22typographer%22%3Atrue%2C%22_highlight%22%3Atrue%2C%22_strict%22%3Afalse%2C%22_view%22%3A%22html%22%7D%7D)) will create three separate blocks with very tight breaks:

````
```
block1
```
```
block2
```
```
block3
```
````

I'm not aware of any way to do this using the indent style as unindented lines (no matter how many you interject) don't break the boxes up:

```
block1





block2


block3
```

Comment: Just interject `<!-->` between the code blocks. I'm tempted to edit your answer to show it, but it's probably better you try for yourself.

Comment: `<!>` is enough. Also ``<?>`` (which is three adjacent keys, but out of order) and many other variants.  I like ``</>``.

Comment: I've always used an empty comment `<!-- -->` or a horizontal line  `---` depending on the situation

Answer (score 0):

Only drawback I could see is being unclear as to which is the 'right way'. But on a whole I think this would be a great feature to add for someone like me who doesn't want to be using either the button above or spacing in.

Comment: But there is not "right way". All ways that works are correct.

Answer (score -2):

The main benefit I see coming from this is that you'll be able to see a little more of the code in the edit box without wrapping. Making it a little easier to specify language is nice too, but I find that the tags take care of it in a large majority of cases.

I'm certainly not opposed, but I don't think it will make fixing code formatting that much easier. You can already select the lines and hit the Code Sample button to add the first level of indent. From there on it's the same amount of work to add additional indents--either copy four spaces and use <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> as a tab key for each line, or copy into editor, fix, and copy back. I think being able to select multiple lines and indent/unindent multiple times would be a lot more helpful than this.

On the downside, ```` ``` ```` would be one of the least intuitive bits of markdown. Doesn't really have the same WYSIWYG feel, at least for me. Using the same sequence to start and end the formatted section could also be a bit confusing, particularly when there are multiple code blocks in a post.

Something like `{{{` to start and `}}}` to end would be clearer, or a custom html tag like, `<codeblock></codeblock>`, or just allow the `<code>` tag to span multiple lines to create a block. *Or*, combine with specifying the language, for example: `<java></java>`.

Comment: It's a big help when you have mixed tabs and spaces, too.

Comment: @bemace I know you can select the lines and then hit the Code button, but as a heavy keyboard user, I find typing three backticks, a line break, `Cmd` + `V`, another line break, and three closing backticks is much faster.

Comment: I like the thought of the language tags `<java></java>`.

Comment: But why invent a new syntax when several existing Markdown implementations already support the triple backtick syntax? Interoperability (and copy-pastability) with other Markdown flavors is a big plus IMHO!

Comment: @MathiasBynens as I explained, with multiple code blocks delimited by ``` separated by a line or two of text (as is common on Stack Overflow) it could get very confusing trying to determine which ``` are *starting* a code block, and which are *ending* a code block-- or rather, which lines are *code* and which are *text*.

Comment: @bemace There would be no confusion if the existing Markdown implementations that support this syntax are followed. Triple backtick code blocks need two line breaks before and after (unless they’re at the start or end of the input).

Comment: @BradMace, It's actually even more confusing to invent a [New Syntax](https://xkcd.com/927/) if there's no **substantial improvement**. There's more people using Github than SE, no harm just following.