# GitHub-style code blocks not recognized when updating code per jsFiddle warning

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, code-formatting

I [edited a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797025/why-does-a-form-with-one-text-input-submit-on-enter-while-one-with-two-text-inpu) on Stack Overflow adding a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) link to a sample fragment. Stack Overflow said:

> Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code

So I added:

````
```  
... my code fragment from jsfiddle  
```
````

Stack Overflow did not like it until I changed it to a four space indented code block.

This looks like a bug.

Steps I took:

1. Added the question without the jsFiddle link
2. Edited the question and added the link
3. Added a code block (delimited by a line of three backticks above and below)
4. Stack Overflow complained
5. Changed to 4-space indent
6. Stack Overflow did not complain any more.

Comment: Could you please show us the exact code you used?  We can't reproduce the problem if you just give us a mock-up.

Comment: It was this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797025/why-does-a-form-with-one-text-input-submit-on-enter-while-one-with-two-text-inpu

Comment: That's the code you got to work; and the code you did not?

Comment: The code that did not work was the same but using 3-backquote (Github) style code block

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This looks like a bug.

Well, no, Stack Exchange doesn't support the GitHub-style code block extension to Markdown (and doesn't claim to anywhere), so this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

That said, fenced code blocks are [under consideration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-markdown-code-blocks) and may be allowed in the future.

Comment: SO supports backquote-code (inline and block). I mean that they work. What do you mean with: "doesn't support" and "may be allowed"?

Comment: No, block level backtick code is not supported. Inline backtick code spans are supported, because they're natively part of markdown. Being able to fence your code with `\`\`\`` is a GitHub extension that SO does not currently support. If you try and do it on SO now, you just get a funky code span.

Comment: In the question body above `… my code fragment from jsfiddle` is written between ```. Why do you say this feature is not supported? Is it because it is not syntax-colored?

Comment: That's one way of looking at it. Your text is in a code *span* there, not a code *block* like the one you'd get on GitHub, or on SO by indenting four spaces, and the edit check looking for accompanying code cares about the presence of a code block.

Comment: When should one use <code> and when a "code block" on SO questions?

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay *Never*, for a `<code>` tag. Use four spaces for indenting a code block, or a single backtick for inline code. There no reason to ever use a literal `<code>` tag. Read the [markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) already!

Comment: @meagar <code> == ```. So, the question was: When should one use 3 x backquote? Answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189920/what-is-the-3-x-backquote-markdown-used-for

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay No, they're not equivalent. You can type a literal `<code>` tag, and that's what is implied when you *say* "<code>". If you want to say `\`\`\`` then say `\`\`\``.