# What is the ``` (3 x backquote) markdown used for?

Tags: discussion, markdown, help, documentation

I looked over https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code but could not find what the Github-style code block markdown is used for on SE websites.

I see that they generate a `<code>` element but [people say](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189914/links-to-jsfiddle-net-must-be-accompanied-by-code-but-so-does-not-recognize-gith) they are not code blocks. What are they then? (any documentation / help). What are they used for?

Example:

`This is written between triple backquotes.`

Comment: To my knowledge, the only difference (between 3 and one backtick) is that three backticks allow for inline backticks without a preceding backslash: ```This is with three: `.``` `This is with one: \`.`

Comment: It's actually documented in the [Help Center's "Editing Help" under "Code Spans" section](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans), but it's not easy to find. You have to click "Code and Preformatted Text" to reveal that section

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three backquotes just resolves to one backquote which is for inline code formatting (as you say it generates `<code>` tags).  IE:

```
`mmmmmmmm stuff`
```

and

````
```mmmmmmmmm stuff```
````

are identical.

Hello I have some `code` here that I'd like to put `inline` with `some number` of backticks.

Etc.

A `code block`, however, includes entire lines; ie, the mmmmmm stuff above could not have been shown (easily) within backtick-delimited inline code.

Comment: Who's playing with the voting again?

Comment: But you *need* multiple backticks if you want to include a backtick in the code itself, like: `\`\`use \`backticks\` in code\`\``.

Answer (score 6):

'Tis known by many names

- code span
- inline code span
- inline code

Code blocks is formed when you indent a line by 4 spaces; inline code span is formed by enclosing text in a pair of backticks.

As documented in [Help Center → Editing Help → Code Spans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans) section:

> If your code itself contains backticks, you may have to use multiple backticks as delimiters:

This is useful in some occasion where the inline code contains literal backticks (**Perl** and **shell** comes to mind, although I'm sure there are more).

1. With the regular single backticks, this markdown

   ```
   `@files = `ls secret`;`
   ```

   would render as

   `@files =`ls secret`;`

   which is totally ugly (I just puked a little in my mouth).
2. With multiple backticks, i.e.

   ```
   ``@files = `ls secret`;``
   ```

   or

   ````
   ```@files = `ls secret`;```
   ````

   you get

   `` @files = `ls secret`; ``

   which is totally hot and correct.

When your code doesn't contain backticks, having single, double, or triple backticks makes no difference.