# Formatting text for better clarity

Tags: support

My questions get downvoted until someone formats it into the required format. For example, if I use an exponent as a^b, people edit it out to its correct form. On looking closer, I found that they use characters such as '$' and '/' to get better looking outputs. I'm sorry if this is a beginner's question, I just really want to learn how to obtain these outputs. The same applies to the comments section, where some of my comments look prehistoric due to lack of formatting.

Comment: [math.se] uses [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) for the formatting of mathematics. Not all SE sites have this enabled, but [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a starting point, and likely more than you need to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use <sup>`<sup></sup>`</sup> to get exponents. Use <sub>`<sub></sub>`</sub> for low text.

---

```
Use four spaces
    to get code.
```

You can also use [code fences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000/323179) to make blocks of code.

Use ``` `` ``` (back ticks) for inline code.

---

You belong to Mathematics SE, which has an expanded list of syntax, MathJax, which has the ability to do super- and sub- scripts, plus any other math formatting you would need. See [here.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/117) Or [here.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020)

Comment: Note that <sup></sup> and <sub></sub> don't work in comments. ​ ​

Comment: True but comments are different. You can't downvote comments, anyway.

Comment: What you describe here is mostly covered in http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help but the MathJax stuff isn't mentioned there.