# Why doesn't Stack Exchange's markdown support traditional code block syntax(``` ... ```)?

Tags: discussion, markdown

In Stack Exchange, we need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to format code.
As we know, most Markdown editors support this syntax:

````
```c++
int main()
{
}
```
````

In Stack Exchange, it will be rendered to:

`c++
int main()
{
}`

While with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, it will be rendered to:

```
int main()
{
}
```

I cannot figure why it isn't supported by Stack Exchange.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks

Comment: Thx. I will delete this question later.

Comment: No need to delete, and looks like my initial assumption was wrong, will write answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Stack Exchange markdown is based on the [original Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), defined in 2004.

Taking a look on [their website](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), it does not define the "Fenced code blocks" syntax, which was added only much later to other markdown extensions.

That's why SE doesn't support it. There is a very popular [feature request asking to support it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks?noredirect=1&lq=1).