# Code formatting XML hides code?

Tags: support, code-formatting

I'm trying to answer my own question on Stack Overflow. I've followed the guides on pasting XML, however it still doesn't show on the answer:

*[The InnerException message was 'Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870224/the-innerexception-message-was-maximum-number-of-items-that-can-be-serialized-o/50798879#50798879)*

I'm not sure if you can see the XML; I can only see it when editing the question. If not, please let me know and I will try paste it here.

Comment: The `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` should _not_ be part of the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed your answer.

You had code in a list, which requires either double the indentation (8 spaces) or what I call a "decoy" tag. I did the latter, with the markdown coming out to:

```
1. Numbered list text

<!>

    code
```

The "decoy" tag is stripped out instead of your actual code. I also use this trick to break code blocks or block quotes into two, by placing `<!>` between the two halves.

Another good alternative is to use [~~~code fences~~~](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000/323179).