# Weird things happening with the new fenced codeblocks

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, markdown-rendering, code-block

If I type this code using the [new fence-style code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125148/388442), it displays fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i = 6;
    while(i --> 0) printf(i);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I add a newline after `int i = 6;` (or any indented section), it displays things weirdly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i = 6;

    while(i --> 0) printf(i);
    return 0;
}
```

It works as expected with 4-space indented code blocks:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i = 6;

    while(i --> 0) printf(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Looking at the HTML structure, it appears that it is creating a code block (from the four spaces indent) within the ``` code block.

Comment: This is fixed on meta, and being deployed to the rest of the network right now (should be done in ~5 minutes). I'll write up an answer with an explanation tomorrow, but it's getting late here :) Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happened here was caused by the fact that there are now two different ways of making a code block. As you noticed, the rendered HTML had a code block inside a codeblock – this occured because I didn't make sure that the two different code block kinds could never overlap, and so that's exactly what happend.

After handling code fences, the intermediary content looked like this:

```
<pre><code>
#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i = 6;

    while(i --&gt; 0) printf(i);
    return 0;
}
</code></pre>
```

Now the "indented code block" logic looked at this result, and it saw an indented code block in the `while` / `return` lines, and thus this happened:

```
<pre><code>
#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i = 6;
<pre><code>
while(i --&amp;gt; 0) printf(i);
return 0;
</code></pre>
}
</code></pre>
```

Once we switch to an actual CommonMark *parser*, this kind of thing can't happen anymore. But right now we're still using the classic "regex replacement" approach to Markdown rendering, and that needs some extra care.