# Where is the list of language names supported by the markdown fenced code blocks?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

Related to [Implement ```-style (fenced) Markdown code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks)

1. On [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58359772/4934640) I used ```` ```makefile ```` and it is "working" the highlighting:

   - [image]
2. However, on [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58360632/4934640), I am also using ```` ```makefile ```` and it is not working the highlighting:

   - [image]

Where is the list of language names supported by the markdown fenced code blocks? Is `makefile` one of them? Perhaps it is called `Makefile`? `makemake`? `toktok`?

The documentation on https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting does not say it either.

Comment: Neither is working for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The list is maintained in the official FAQ:

[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Do note that `makefile` is not in this list. The reason you see some *effect* is caused by the fallback that is used for unknown prettifiers:  It uses `default` and that effectively means it take a guess, does a best effort. See also my answer on Meta.SO: [What is the default language for the syntax highlighter?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327673/what-is-the-default-language-for-the-syntax-highlighter/327677#327677)

I advice you to first use a supported highligther and go from there.

Comment: What is the diff between extension and core? E.g. **Ruby** has ext. rb, but is in core.

Comment: @user3123159 thanks, I have removed that obsolete list. Please visit the actual maintained list in the FAQ post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: On the SE sites, the language is autodetected by **tags** according to your link (no need for the language name after **three backticks**). Whereas on Github, you have to name the language after the three backticks, this is the official md style (```markdown).

Comment: @user3123159 not all tags have a highlighter hint and some tags have notoriously weird  default selections.