# Four space indentation doesn't format as code immediately after newline

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting, newline

The next line is indented by 4 spaces and should appear as code:
    This should appear as code

Picture of issue:
[image]

Possibly related to [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3327/167443)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, code blocks have to be

```
separated from ordinary text by a blank line.
```

It's by design.