# How do correctly display code blocks after a bullet list?

Tags: discussion, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)

As part of [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10734369/122457) I entered a code block. The code however was not being displayed in the markup, it was just plain text with no line breaks. I tried multiple times copying and pasting it in, entering tabs/spaces for the indents and highlighting it and clicking the 'Code Sample' button.

**Here is an example of the failure case...**

1. Here is a list item. The code direclty after is not formatted correctly.

   import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
   import java.text.DateFormat

   Date timeDate1 = new Date().parse("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z","18-05-2012 09:29:41 +0800")
   Date timeDate2 = new Date().parse("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z","18-05-2012 09:29:21 +0900")

After further testing it seems that if you enter source code directly after a list then the code will not be formatted correctly.

How do correctly display code blocks after a bullet list?

Answer (score 2):

Enter a dash - character on it's own line after the bullet list.

1. The code below works (with the dash character the code block displays correctly formatted). E.g.:

-

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.text.DateFormat

Date timeDate1 = new Date().parse("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z","18-05-2012 09:29:41 +0800")
Date timeDate2 = new Date().parse("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z","18-05-2012 09:29:21 +0900")
```

This however seems like a work around. I would think it should be possible to display code after a list without needing to add an extra unnecessary character.

Comment: It is, just indent *8* spaces, rather than 4.

Comment: @TheEstablishment But that makes the code block part of the last list item. A `<!-- comment -->` between list and code block works without displaying a stray extra character (but is more work than typing a single dash).