# Why does indenting this code 4 spaces not work?

Tags: bug, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)

I wanted to have this code in my post, and I indented things by four spaces. As you can see, it works fine here.

```
# Spine.app had these as dependencies by default
require('json2ify')
require('es5-shimify')
require('jqueryify')

require('spine')
require('spine/lib/local')
require('spine/lib/ajax')
require('spine/lib/manager')
require('spine/lib/route')

# d3 was installed via dependencies.json
require 'd3/d3.v2'
```

but in my actual post (I answered a question), it looks like crap and was not rendered properly:
[spine.js hem server, hem build FAQ for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425368/)

What is going on?

Comment: Because you wrote it inside bullets.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item

Comment: Actually, @MrLister, since the goal is to help future visitors just as much as the op, and since there are N possible future visitors and only one op, it's perfectly fine, and encouraged, to answer older questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use additional 4 more space (total 8 space) to write code inside bullets like this one.

```
Code with 4 space outside bullet.
Code with 4 space outside bullet.
```

1. Example of bullet.
2. Example of bullet.

   ```
   Code inside bullet with 8 space.
   Code inside bullet with 8 space.
   ```
3. Example of bullet.

Comment: It would still be nice if the Ctrl-K/code block shortcut did this. Otherwise it's just a pain in the butt to add each of those 4 extra spaces manually.