# Why can't I format my code in this answer?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to nest code within a list using markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13169659/57135

I know how to format code, but can't get it to work in this answer.  Not sure why?

Comment: Dup. of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148385/187824 & http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3327/187824

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were inside a list, so the four spaces were being interpreted as continuing the list, not starting a code block. You needed to add *another* four spaces to indent it as code. I've fixed it for you.