# Code formatting when putting in #'s

Tags: bug, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)

Okay, so if I'm posting a code block after a number, the formatting doesn't work. If you take a look at my view by editing it, you will see that it looks correct.

1. This is a test

   Test code
   Test line 2

And then I put a normal line, copy the above text exactly, and:

```
Test code
Test line 2
```

Any chance of getting this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

1. `This is a test`
   `Test line 2`

seems to me that the formatting is off (as far as new lines go) but there's a meta post that covered that somewhere (I'll see if I can find it, and post the link here)

EDIT: using the `<br>` HTML tag I can force a new line, just use the ` character (beside the 1 on the keyboard) to end/restart the code around it.

what I typed above: `` This is a test`<br>`Test line 2 ``

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra 4 spaces when you have code just after a list item:

1. This is a test

   ```
   Test code
   Test line 2
   ```